# How to display retrieved MySQL information on another page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

This code shows the information (kind of like a confirmation or review) of what the user submitted in the form.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $_POST['info1'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $_POST['info2'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $_POST['info3'];
}
?>
```

I don't want to put it on the same page as my form. How can I make it so I put it on another .php page?

EDIT: I already have the code where the everything saves to the database when the user submits the form. How can I display the information that the user just submitted to that user on another page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write inser query for the above code. Then You can get it using Select query. You can get help from [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) about writing simple mysql query. I hope that will helpful for you

Comment: I already have the code where the everything saves to the database when the user submits the form. How can I display the information that the user just submitted to that user on another page?

Comment: You can simply pass the insert data from where you pass this data to display.php as an array to function. e.g. display($_POST); In display definition add display($array = array){echo $array['infoq'];}

Comment: fell free if you have confusion in any thing